# After I capture an image the labels are not return, Is my code right?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments

```
private class InferenceThread extends AsyncTask <Bitmap , Integer , FirebaseModelInputs> {
        String labels;
        @Override
        protected FirebaseModelInputs doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
            try {
                        inputOutputOptions =
                        new FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions.Builder()
                                .setInputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, new int[]{1, 1152, 896, 1})
                                .setOutputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, new int[]{1, 2})
                                .build();
            } catch (FirebaseMLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap , 1152 ,896 , true);

            int batchNum = 0 ;
            float[][][][] input = new float[1][1152][896][1];

            for (int x = 0; x < 1152; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < 896; y++) {
                    int pixel = imageBitmap.getPixel(x, y);
                    // Normalize channel values to [-1.0, 1.0]. This requirement varies by
                    // model. For example, some models might require values to be normalized
                    // to the range [0.0, 1.0] instead.
                    input[batchNum][x][y][0] = (Color.red(pixel) - 127) / 128.0f;
//                    input[batchNum][x][y][1] = (Color.green(pixel) - 127) / 128.0f;
//                    input[batchNum][x][y][2] = (Color.blue(pixel) - 127) / 128.0f;
                }
            }

            FirebaseModelInputs inputs = null;
            try {
                inputs = new FirebaseModelInputs.Builder()
                        .add(input)  // add() as many input arrays as your model requires
                        .build();

            } catch (FirebaseMLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return inputs;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(FirebaseModelInputs inputs) {
            super.onPostExecute(inputs);

            interpreter.run(inputs, inputOutputOptions).addOnSuccessListener(
                    new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseModelOutputs>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FirebaseModelOutputs result) {
                            d("Hellow", "Success");
                            float[][] output = result.getOutput(0);
                            float[] probabilities = output[0];

                            BufferedReader reader = null;
                            try {
                                reader = new BufferedReader(
                                        new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open("labels.txt")));
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e("Label file not read" , "file not buffered" , e);
                            }
                            for (int i = 0; i < probabilities.length; i++) {
                                String label = null;
                                try {
                                    label = reader.readLine();
                                    d("Labels", label);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e("line not read" , "labels not identified" ,e);
                                }
                                i("MLKit", String.format("%s: %1.4f", label, probabilities[i]));
                                labels = label;
                            }
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    d("Hellow", "Failure");
                }
            });
            //resulttextbox.setText(labels);
        }
    }
```

What I am trying to do here is , getting the model instance and doing and inference on it . The model is located on the firebase custom model. I am doing inference in a Async class . What I knew is that , my code is not running and inference.

What I am trying to achieve in my application is basically a camera application takes a picture and run on the model located remotely on the firebase custom model.

If anybody can help please answer .

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300 (three hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Okay, thankyou as I am new to this community so ,didnot knew how will I get help , I will edit this question.